# Highlight and paste the text when a string/char is removed from textarea using thymeleaf + springboot

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am stuck in one of the tricky tasks. I am using thymeleaf and have some strings separated by newLine. All I want is when someone add/remove the text from the text area. When I click on the checkbox, it should show me what is removed and what is added. Until now what I did is only tell me the added scopes.

**HTML:**

```
<input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" required onclick="addOrRemoveScope()"/>
<label for="checkbox">Are you sure, you want to modify the scopes?*</label><br>
<span id="scopeResult" style="display: none"></span>
```

**JS:**

```
        function addOrRemoveScope() {
          var checkBox = document.getElementById('checkbox');
          var scopes = document.getElementById('scopeResult');
            if(checkBox.checked == true){
              scopes.style.display = 'block';
              document.getElementById("scopeResult").innerHTML = document.getElementById('scopes').value;
            } else {
              scopes.style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
```

Any suggestions will be great.
Thanks.

Comment: At the moment when "something is removed from the textarea" you are dealing with regular HTML, Thymeleaf has already done to work at server-side and deliver to your browser pure HTML. For in Browser solutions to manipulate with DOM use client-side technology, for example, JavaScript.

Comment: @SlavaIvanov do you have any example for JS?

Comment: No, I don't have one. I would advise you to try just google "javascript textarea text change event" request, there are plenty of examples including SO. After try to implement something on your own, and only after that, if something still doesn't work, ask another specific question related to your JS. At the end, nobody will write code for you, please do your part first. Best regards,

Comment: @SlavaIvanov I edit the question